# How to add multiple functions to Kendo read?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I want to apply two funtions for filter inside read.I am not sure How to invoke two functions on kendo filter , its throwing syntax error. Please help here...
main.js

```
read : function(options) {
    var gridSearchObject = {
      skip: options.data.skip,
      take: options.data.take,
      pageSize: options.data.pageSize,
      page: options.data.page,
      sorting: options.data.sort,
      filter: pupulateCustomFilters(riskAssessmentSearchDTO),interceptFilter(options.data.filter)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

What you can do is create your custom filter like this:

```
dataSource.filter({
    field: "FieldName",
    operator: function(item, value){
        //implement your logic
    },
    value: 12
})
```

`filter` is just an array which can be custom build using your function.

Comment: Thanks it helps to conclude the solution